# react - remove element from list unintentionally clears object properties

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState({
    title: "",
    number: 6,
    questions: [
      {
        question: "q1",
        number: 3,
        answers: [
          {
            content: "a1",
            number: 1.5
          },
          {
            content: "a2",
            number: 1.5
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  });

  const [selectedQuestion, setSelectedQuestion] = useState(0);
  const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedQuestion(0);
    setSelectedAnswer(0);
  }, []);
```

This console log is the desired output:

```
console.log(quiz.questions[selectedQuestion].answers.filter((element, index) => index !== selectedAnswer))
```

I am trying to achieve it with this setState:

```
        setQuiz((prev) => ({
          ...prev, questions: prev.questions.map((question, x) => {
            if (x === selectedQuestion) { 
                console.log(question.answers.filter((element, y) => y !== selectedAnswer ))
              return question.answers.filter((element, y) => y !== selectedAnswer )
            }
            return question;
        })
      }));
```

All the data inside parent question will be deleted instead in addition to the selected answer.

This is the data before deleting:

[image]

This is the data after deleting:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic code is in this block:

```
if (x === selectedQuestion) { 
    console.log(question.answers.filter((element, y) => y !== selectedAnswer ))
    return question.answers.filter((element, y) => y !== selectedAnswer )
}
```

If the mapping function encounters the selected question, it only maps the question to the filtered answers,  without the remaining question data.
I suggest you replace the `return` statement as follows:

```
if (x === selectedQuestion) {
  const answers = question.answers.filter((element, y) => y !== selectedAnswer);
  console.log(answers);
  return { ...question, answers };
}
```